# dynamically set caller id to Twilio number

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-api

Is it possible in twilio to set caller id on-the-fly. I know you ca set Caller Id by verifying the number from  twilio but how I can achieve following use case -

I have 5 different number and one twilio number which I used to call to user, now my use case is I need to set caller id among these 5 numbers to twilio number based on some condition dynamically e.g. `.setCallerId()`.

**Update 1:**

I am using below code to initiate a call -

```
Call call = Call
                .creator(new PhoneNumber(to), new PhoneNumber(from),
                        new URI(url)).create();
```

Here url I am passing which actually play an IVR message for user.

```
Say say = new Say.Builder(announcement).voice(Say.Voice.WOMAN)
                .language(Language.EN_US).loop(4).build();
        Pause pause = new Pause.Builder().length(1).build();

        voiceResponse = new VoiceResponse.Builder()
                .say(say)
                .pause(pause)
                .build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can only set the caller ID on a call to either numbers you have bought within Twilio or numbers that you have verified.

When you connect a Twilio call to another caller using TwiML you can [set the caller ID using an attribute on the `<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#callerid). For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial callerId="+15551112222">
        <Number>+15558675310</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

In Java, that would look a bit like:

```
import com.twilio.twiml.voice.Dial;
import com.twilio.twiml.voice.Number;
import com.twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse;
import com.twilio.twiml.TwiMLException;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Number number = new Number.Builder("+15558675310").build();
        Dial dial = new Dial.Builder().callerId("+15551112222").number(number)
            .build();
        VoiceResponse response = new VoiceResponse.Builder().dial(dial).build();

        try {
            System.out.println(response.toXml());
        } catch (TwiMLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this information. I have updated my question with twilio API which I am using to initiate a call. Can you please let me know in this case how I can assign callerId.

Comment: Oh, then the caller ID is the number you use as the `From` parameter in requests to the API. The same restrictions count, you can only use Twilio numbers or numbers you have verified.

Comment: but how I can assign caller id as I am not using Dial class. Can you please give me an example.

Comment: In your code where you use `Call.creator(new PhoneNumber(to), new PhoneNumber(from), new URI(url)).create();` the second `PhoneNumber` parameter is the caller ID.

Comment: Oh, ok. One more thing that I mention in question I have 5 numbers so If I verified all those numbers from Twilio then I can use those numbers as a caller id (the second `PhoneNumber`) in my code based on some condition?